# Why aren't buffers auto-flushed by default?

Tags: perl, buffer, autoflush

I recently had the privilege of setting [`$| = 1;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) inside my Perl script to help it talk faster with another application across a pipe.

I'm curious as to why this is not the default setting. In other words, what do I lose out on if my buffer gets flushed straightaway?

Comment: Faster? No, probably not, because it will be woken up more often. It will have lower latency, though.

Comment: I often wish the same. I'm, not convinced the benefit is worth all the trouble it gives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Benchmark it and you will understand.

Buffered depends on the **device type** of the output handle: ttys are line-buffered; pipes and sockets are pipe-buffered; disks are block-buffered.

This is just basic programming.  It’s not a Perl thing.

Answer (score 13):

Writing to a file descriptor is done via system calls, and system calls are slow.

Buffering a stream and flushing it only once some amount of data has been written is a way to save some system calls.

Comment: And packets. And disk writes. And ... pretty much anything that works better with more than a few bytes of data at a time :)

Answer (score 3):

The fewer times the I/O buffer is flushed, the faster your code is in general (since it doesn't have to make a system call as often). So your code spends more time waiting for I/O by enabling auto-flush.

In a purely network I/O-driven application, that obviously makes more sense. However, in the most common use cases, line-buffered I/O (Perl's default for TTYs) allows the program to flush the buffer less often and spend more time doing CPU work. The average user wouldn't notice the difference on a terminal or in a file.

Comment: So in other words, it makes sense to auto-flush if I'm expecting a continual stream of data through the pipe as the code won't be waiting around as much. Did I get that right?

Comment: No, just send all the headers all at once. It does not matter to linebuffer them. Everything always reads all the headers.

Comment: How is it better to flush after each header newline instead only at the double-newline at the end?

Comment: A large HTTP header line like `User-Agent` is only about 120 bytes. A short line may be less than 20 bytes. With a typical MTU more than 20 HTTP header lines should easily fit in a packet. If you line buffer your HTTP headers most network stacks will spit out a packet per line. Resulting in a 20x increase in TCP/IP overhead. HTTP is an perfect example of a protocol that should not be line buffered, on the other hand IRC is and equally perfect example of a protocol that should be line buffered.